# Parallel CRC polynomial

Tags: verilog, crc

I want to write a parallel CRC for the CRC_8_ATM polynomial. I found this [code](https://www.asic-world.com/examples/verilog/parallel_crc.html) for polynomial = 0x1021 but I do not understand the XORs positions and why they are like this so that I can change it to my desired polynomial

```
assign crc_out = crc_reg;
// CRC Control logic
always @ (posedge clk)
if (reset) begin
  crc_reg <= 16'hFFFF;
end else if (enable) begin
  if (init) begin
     crc_reg <= 16'hFFFF;
  end else begin
     crc_reg <= next_crc;
  end
end
// I do not understand this part
assign next_crc[0] = data_in[7] ^ data_in[0] ^ crc_reg[4] ^ crc_reg[11];
assign next_crc[1] = data_in[1] ^ crc_reg[5];
assign next_crc[2] = data_in[2] ^ crc_reg[6];
assign next_crc[3] = data_in[3] ^ crc_reg[7];
assign next_crc[4] = data_in[4] ^ crc_reg[8];
assign next_crc[5] = data_in[7] ^ data_in[5] ^ data_in[0] ^ crc_reg[4] ^ crc_reg[9] ^ crc_reg[11];
assign next_crc[6] = data_in[6] ^ data_in[1] ^ crc_reg[5] ^ crc_reg[10];
assign next_crc[7] = data_in[7] ^ data_in[2] ^ crc_reg[6] ^ crc_reg[11];
assign next_crc[8] = data_in[3] ^ crc_reg[0] ^ crc_reg[7];
assign next_crc[9] = data_in[4] ^ crc_reg[1] ^ crc_reg[8];
assign next_crc[10] = data_in[5] ^ crc_reg[2] ^ crc_reg[9];
assign next_crc[11] = data_in[6] ^ crc_reg[3] ^ crc_reg[10];
```

Comment: "I found this code for polynomial" ... where did you find the code?

Comment: here https://www.asic-world.com/examples/verilog/parallel_crc.html (I add this to my question)

Comment: Before you modify code to do something else, you should first check that it works as claimed. It allocates 16 wires for `next_crc`, but it only defines 12 of them! This implements, at best, a 12-bit linear function over GF(2) of the `data_in` values (likely not even a CRC), where the high four bits of the 16-bit output register `crc_reg` are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you're looking for for a non-reflected CRC with truncated polynomial `0x07` is the following, where `c` is the exclusive-or of the previous CRC value and the data byte, and `cp` ("c prime"), is the next CRC value:

```
assign cp[0] = c[0] ^ c[6] ^ c[7];
assign cp[1] = c[0] ^ c[1] ^ c[6];
assign cp[2] = c[0] ^ c[1] ^ c[2] ^ c[6];
assign cp[3] = c[1] ^ c[2] ^ c[3] ^ c[7];
assign cp[4] = c[2] ^ c[3] ^ c[4];
assign cp[5] = c[3] ^ c[4] ^ c[5];
assign cp[6] = c[4] ^ c[5] ^ c[6];
assign cp[7] = c[5] ^ c[6] ^ c[7];
```

This is computed by taking the eight bits at each step, `a[0]`..`a[7]` symbolically, shifting them up one bit, and exclusive-oring the low three bits with the `a[7]` in that step (that represents the polynomial `0x07`, which has the low three bits set). Repeat eight times, and you get the expressions above.